# NPE on fragments text field - why?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I want to change the text of my `TextView` element, which is defined in the corresponding `QuoteFragment.class` file and the related `layout.xml` file. You can see the code of the method in my main activity:

```
private void forwardToQuoteFragment(Quote quote){
    quoteFragment = QuoteFragment.newInstance(quote);
    View view = quoteFragment.getView();
    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.quoteFragmentHeader);
    tv.setText("Quote (" + quote.getId() + "): " + quote.getQuote());
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.container, quoteFragment);
    ft.commit();
}
```

My debugger tells me, that the view variable is null, therefore I got an NPE. It will make no difference, if I created the view-property in my `QuoteFragment.class`, which you can see below:

```
public class QuoteFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    public static final String QUOTE_FRAGMENT_TAG = "QuoteFragment";
    public static final String QUOTE_ID = "quoteId";
    private View view;
    private long quoteId;

    public QuoteFragment(){
        // required
    }

    // factory to set arguments
    public static QuoteFragment newInstance(Quote quote) {
        QuoteFragment fragment = new QuoteFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putLong(QUOTE_ID, quote.getId()); 
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context){
        super.onAttach(context);
        Log.i(QUOTE_FRAGMENT_TAG, "onAttach()");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i(QUOTE_FRAGMENT_TAG, "onCreate()");
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_quote, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    public void setQuoteId(long id){
        this.quoteId = id;
    }

    public long getQuoteId() {
        return quoteId;
    }

    public View getView(){
       return this.view;
    }
}
```

What is the best way to solve this issue? What did I overlooked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't get the `View`, because the `View` was not drawn to the screen yet:
`onCreateView()` inside your `Fragment` has not been called, yet, but you are already trying to access the `TextView` which only will be created when `onCreateView()` is called.

You need to set the text inside the `OnCreateView()` method like so

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_quote, container, false);
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.quoteFragmentHeader);
        tv.setText("Quote (" + quote.getId() + "): " + quote.getQuote());
        return view;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Steve - I will give it a try. 

I thought if the TextView is marked in the layout.xml it will get created?! 

Anyway I am not sure if your approach will solve my issue, because I got the information, which text should be printed in my MainActivity and not my Fragment. That was the reason, why I wanted to grab the TextView from the Fragment in my activity and call the corresponding setter-method.

Comment: The simplest way of getting your `Qoute` is by putting it in your `Bundle` as a `String`, which you are creating in the `newInstance()` method:         `args.putString(QUOTE_QUOTE, quote.getQoute());`

Comment: Or you could take a slightly more complex approce by using [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) and the putting the whole `Qoute` in the Bundle as a `Parcelable`

Comment: Thanks a lot - the approach by giving the parameters by bundle worked out great!